# Does advice reduce depth?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, circuit-depth

Specifically I'm thinking about NC$^1$/poly and NC$^1$/rpoly (randomized advice). Are there any statements like

"If $\{C_n\}$ is a family of NC$^1$/(r)poly circuits with depth $C\log n$, then there exists a family $\{\tilde{C}_n\}$ of NC$^1$/(r)poly circuits with depth $\tilde{C}\log n$ such that $\tilde{C} < 1$ and $C_n(x) = \tilde{C}_n(x)$"?

Or would that be too powerful?

Comment: What is randomized advice? Is that stronger or weaker than normal advice?

Comment: As far as I can tell, with usual advice, i.e., non-uniform $\mathrm{NC}^1$ circuits, the statement is as false as possible: for any $d<n-\log n$ or so (such as $C\log n$), there exist functions computable by circuits of depth $d+1$, but not by circuits of depth $d$. Proof: if not, then *all* Boolean functions are computable by circuits of depth $d$, and therefore size $2^d$, as you can just take an arbitrary circuit, and keep reducing subcircuits of depth $d+1$ to $d$ until none remain. However, almost all functions require circuit size $\Omega(2^n/n)$.

Comment: Of course, with $\tilde C<1$ as written, it’s much easier to disprove: a circuit of depth $\tilde C\log n$ with $\tilde C<1$ has size at most $n^{\tilde C}<n$, hence it cannot even depend on all bits of the input. Thus, even simple functions such as $\mathrm{AND}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ have no circuits of depth $\tilde C\log n$.

Comment: I see, this can't be true then. Thanks.